# How do i get the data from a ui picker view with more than one scroller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uipickerview

Im trying to use a ui picker view that has 3 scroll option but i cant get it to spit out the options selected when I hit my submit button but it is just giving 1, 2, 3 here is my code code (also doont mind the bottom bit its my incomplete alert messages)

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
```

class PitcherPickerViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

`var ref: Firebase!

@IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var age: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var paragraph: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var playerNum: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var innings: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var topBlue: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var back: UIButton!
@IBAction func submit1(sender: AnyObject) {
    ref.setValue(pickerData)

}


 var pickerData: [[String]] = [[String]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = Firebase(url: "https://baseball-pitcher-app.firebaseIO.com/")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Connect data:
    self.picker.delegate = self
    self.picker.dataSource = self

    // Input data into the Array:
    pickerData = [["8", "9", "10"],
        ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99"],
        ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// The number of columns of data
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

// The number of rows of data
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData[component].count
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerData[component][row]
}

// Catpure the picker view selection
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    // This method is triggered whenever the user makes a change to the picker selection.
    // The parameter named row and component represents what was selected.
}

func displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage:String)
{
    var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Oh No! ", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)

    myAlert.addAction(okAction)

    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }`

}

here is a picture of the scroller
[ui picker image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWIh0.png)

I've been stumped for like almost a week now and cant seem to figure this out for the life of me thanks for the help.

Comment: What code have you tried within pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent? What is it about the row and component parameters to that method that you do not understand how to use?

Comment: Also, where is the code that runs when you press the submit button? The @IBAction method?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the selected item in 3 different components it's probably easiest if you write a method that calls the picker view's `selectedRowInComponent` 3 separate times, one for each component (passing in component value of 0, 1, and 2.)

### EDIT:

I suggest putting that logic in the `IBAction` for your submit button.

You can also put logic in the didSelectRow:inComponent method that saves the selected component each time it changes, but that's more work and probably more confusing for a beginner.